# go through ArrayList and cannot find the object

Tags: java, swing

I want to login to the system as a customer, who has an ID and account number. When the customer's number is input, I am going through an `ArrayList` of customers without issue.

When I input an account number, my program goes through an `ArrayList` of accounts for that particular customer and opens a dialog which is not associated with that account.

I would like to have the `ArrayList` find the input account number and do a transaction for that particular number.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(" ");
    boolean found1 = false;
    boolean found = false;

    String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the ID number: ");      
    for(Customer aCustomer: customers){
        System.out.println("ID: " + a + " = " + aCustomer.getId());

        int num = Integer.parseInt(a);  

        if(num == aCustomer.getId()){
            BankInterface.setCurrentCustomer(aCustomer);
            found1 = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found1){    
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "There is no customer with this ID number", "Please try again", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }

    if(found1){      
        String b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the account number: ");    
        int number = Integer.parseInt(b);   
        for(CustomerAccount cu: BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer().getAccounts()){ 
            System.out.println("Account: " + b + " = " + cu.getAccountNumber());
            if(number == cu.getAccountNumber()){
                //BankInterface.setCurrentCustomer(aCustomer);
                BankInterface.setCurrentAccount(cu);
                new WithdrawDepositDialog(BankInterface.this, customers);
                found = true;

                }

            }
        }
    }
});
```

Once the dialog is open, I am trying to get what I set in my driver class to connect with the particular account number.

By the way, I add transactions to the array of transactions, which I have in an  Account class:

```
AccountTransaction transactions = new AccountTransaction(date, type, amount);

BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer();
BankInterface.getCurrentAccount();
int arraySize =  BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer().getAccounts().size();

Customer tempCust = BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer();
for(Customer c : customers){
    if(c == tempCust){
        for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){ 
            c.getAccounts().get(i).getTransactions().add(transactions);
            c.getAccounts().get(i).withdraw(amount);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `(c == tempCust)` this compares an object reference, are you sure you don't mean to do `(c.equals(tempCust))`?

Comment: I changed, I am not sure, what is the proper way. but I still have the same mistake...

Comment: Is your Customer class implementing equals method?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information. In addition, what is the output of your program (the information printed by the `println` statements)? Which accounts are in the list, which account gets picked, and which were you expecting to get picked?

Comment: Are you sure `customers` is filled? Where do you fill it? Try to print the List first and check manually if the ID is contained in there. Does your sysout print something? I see you have one in the loop.